# UISplitviewController + Issue regarding the Layout of Detail controller

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

I am facing one issue regarding Layout of detail view in UISplitviewController. below is application flow.

```
   [window addsubview:PreLoginController.view]
```

2. Application launches with Login Screen [ Master = number of options + login button Detail = detail of option selected from Master ]
3. User clicks "Login" and one view [ full screen like present modalview controller ] appeared, user fills the detail and click Login button

   [window addsubview:PostLoginController.view]
4. User Clicks "Log out"

   [window addsubview:PreLoginController.view]

*Problem lies here - Detail page appeared with width 427 and black patch is displayed. when Detail page is displayed properly at that time width is 748.

Why calling [window addsubview:PreLoginController.view] second time affecting width disturbance.

Please help me on this.

thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please follow the below steps to resolve the issue.

1. Load the splitview normally.
2. For log-in, use the presentModelViewController to load the log-in view.

Don't add the views.

Regards,
vijay